# No module named 'config' and No module named 'model' in GoogleColab

Tags: python, image-processing, python-import, google-colaboratory

I tried to import in Colab, but it does not mention the name of a module.

```
from config import Config
from model import CSRNet
```

I am writing this code and as a result I get it.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: But have you installed both?

Comment: But it is google colab. Am I have to install them ?

Comment: Is this https://pypi.org/project/config/ one are you  trying to use?

Comment: For install in Google colab try with this  !pip install config

Comment: İt works thank you

Comment: Don't forget it that Google colab is like a VM.....and maybe after you will need install again

Answer (score 0):

Make you sure have you installed ...for Google colab try with this:

!pip install config